# How to query usagestatsmanager for daily, weekly or monthly usage in android?

Tags: android, cpu-usage, usage-statistics, usagestatsmanager

I am working one of android application in which I want to track all installed applications usage with daily, weekly, monthly and overall summary reporting options. For this I use usagestatsmanager but the result i get its not correct in daily or monthly usage. So any one plz help me out that how to query usagestatsmanager for daily, weekly or monthly usage ? The query which i use are given below :-

```
public List<UsageStats> stats;
```

for **daily usage**

```
//Calendar for query
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, -1);

//List<UsageStats> Query UsageStatsManager for List<UsageStats>
stats = mUsageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, cal.getTimeInMillis(), System.currentTimeMillis());
```

for **weekly usage**

```
//Calendar for query
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -5);

//List<UsageStats> Query UsageStatsManager for List<UsageStats>
stats=mUsageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_WEEKLY, cal.getTimeInMillis(), System.currentTimeMillis());
```

for **monthly usage**

```
//Calendar for query
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -5);

//List<UsageStats> Query UsageStatsManager for List<UsageStats>
stats=mUsageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_MONTHLY,
cal.getTimeInMillis(), System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Comment: Show us what you are doing and the results. Tell us what you do expect to see them we may be able to help

Comment: Thanks @Binary Dev, but can you edit the original question. That way your code can be formatted for readability

Comment: @Mike Ok I edit my que.

Comment: did anyone find answer